# How many roots of complex equation given in an interval

Tags: complex-analysis

> Given $z^4-5z+1=0$. Determine how many roots of that equation on $1 \leq |z| \leq 2$.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem? Honestly, I have tried some classic ways but that interval giving me a headache. Does that mean the roots are bounded between $1$ and $2$? Please give me your help

Comment: The bounds on complex roots section might help. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Complex_conjugate_root_theorem         Rouche's theorem might help more https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem

Comment: If you know how, find all the roots and ignore the interval. Then say which of those are in the interval. The question is not saying that *all* the roots are in that interval, it is only interested in the roots that happen to be in that interval.

Comment: @diligar: $1\leq|z|\leq 2$ is not an interval but an annulus if, as I believe, *roots* stands for *complex roots*.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I meant to say a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, not an interval. Thank you!

Comment: $\frac{1}{2 \pi}\oint_{|z|=a} \frac{1}{f(z)} dz$ gives the number of roots of f(z) in the circle radius a centered at the origin.

Comment: Of course $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=\rho}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz$ returns the number of roots of $f$ inside $|z|<\rho$, but we do not really need to compute/approximate such integral (or invoke Rouché theorem) to provide an answer. Since the degree is $4$ and we have $2$ real roots, one of them being very close to $1/5$, all roots except the latter lie in the annulus $\frac{8}{5}<|z|<\frac{7}{4}$. We only need real techniques and Newton's method to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

$1\leq |z|\leq 2$ means $1\leq |z|\leq 2$, i.e. that the modulus of $z$ is bounded between $1$ and $2$.
It is not difficult to prove that our polynomial has a real root very close to $\frac{1}{5}$, another real root between $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{7}{4}$, no other real root.  This leaves out a couple of conjugate complex roots $\zeta,\overline{\zeta}$. Since by Vieta's formulas the product of the roots equals $1$, $|\zeta|^2$ is between $\frac{20}{7}$ and $\frac{10}{3}$. It follows that $\zeta,\overline{\zeta}$ belong to the annulus $1\leq |z|\leq 2$ and our polynomial has three roots in such region.

Answer (score 0):

You get $|5z|>|z^4+1|$ for $|z|=1$ and $|z^4|>|5z+1|$ for $|z|=2$ which allows you via Rouché to find the number of roots in the disks with radius $1$ and $2$ and per subtraction of the sets the number of roots in the annulus.